# DocuSign API - Retrieve Envelope JSON for Envelope Sent via Admin Page

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the [Envelopes: create API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) in the sandbox to send signing requests successfully. I'm now working on one that involves DocuSign Templates and two template roles, so that each recipient should only complete their own fields for name, date and signature.

This is working fine when using the DocuSign Admin webpage to send these, but with my API request, the first recipient/role can fill in all fields for both recipients.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here and was wondering if I can somehow view/retrieve the JSON data for the envelopes that are not sent via the API but using the DocuSign admin webpage.

For example I'm after the following data so I can compare this to my request:

```
{
"accountId": "301424",
"emailSubject": "API Example - Populating Data in Templates",
"templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
"templateRoles": [{
    "email": "john.doe@email.com",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "roleName": "Customer",
    "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [{
            "tabLabel": "CustomerAddress",
            "value": "123 Main St. San Francisco, CA 94105"
        }, 
        {
            "tabLabel": "CustomerSSN",
            "value": "12-345-6789"
        }]
    }
}],
"status": "sent"
}
```

Is it possible, knowing the Envelope ID, to retrieve the JSON that was used to generate the Envelope/signing request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the requests that the DocuSign web tool made to create your envelope by using the [API request logging feature](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging). However, the web tool often uses multiple API calls to create an envelope. You can do the same, or coalesce the multiple calls into one.

If you ask a new question and supply the JSON that you're using, we may be able to spot your mistake directly.

For example, are you using two different email addresses for your two template roles in your test?

Do you have the tabs/fields set so they can only be modified by the specific recipient?

Are you creating the template programmatically or are you using the DocuSign web tool to create the template?

Comment: Thanks - I worked out the issue here. I thought you needed to supply the document tabs for the envelope that are already on the template, so I was in effect including them twice. Once I removed the tabs it now works fine.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear. @user982124